# Formik displaying wrong error message when Yup async test is used

Tags: formik, yup

Versions:

`formik: 2.2.6`

`yup: 0.32.8`

I've been having this issue with formik today so I set about creating a minimally reproducible example.

In the example you'll see that we have different validators attached to the `data` field including: `required`, `length(6)` and an async `test`.

When the correct conditions are met for an error message to show, you'll notice that the wrong error message is shown until the async `test` resolves. You'll also notice that between the wrong message showing, and the async `test` resolving, `formik.isValidating` is false.

What are we doing wrong here and how can we prevent this incorrect error message from showing up?

Additionally, how can we get `formik.isValidating` to return `true` when the async `test` is yet to resolve? If we could do that we could indicate to the user that validation is still pending.

Minimal Reproducible Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/black-shape-z5e54?file=/src/App.js

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { useFormik } from "formik";
import * as yup from "yup";

const asyncTest = (value, context) => {
  return new Promise((res) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      res(context.createError({ message: "This ain't right" }));
    }, 3000);
  });
};

const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
  data: yup
    .string()
    .required("Data is required")
    .length(6)
    .test("async-val", "", asyncTest)
});

export default function App() {
  const formik = useFormik({
    validationSchema,
    initialValues: {
      data: ""
    }
  });

  // A helper to simulate a field that auto blurs
  // when completing. In the real code, handleBlur is called
  // when the pin input reaches its sixth character.
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (formik.values.data.length >= 6) {
      inputRef.current.blur();
    }
  }, [formik.values.data]);

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="data"
        ref={inputRef}
        value={formik.values.data}
        onChange={formik.handleChange}
        onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
      />
      {formik.errors.data && formik.touched.data && (
        <div>{formik.errors.data}</div>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: did you found any solution for this

Comment: @KathirpandianK We actually moved away from using formik and replaced it with react-final-form.